# Inserting a row in a table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm trying to insert a new row into a table with a javascript object.

The HTML looks like this:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("userTable");

var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");

var fn = document.createTextNode(user.firstname);
var ln = document.createTextNode(user.lastname);
var score = document.createTextNode(user.score);

td.appendChild(fn);
td.appendChild(ln);
td.appendChild(score);

tr.appendChild(td);
table.appendChild(tr);
```

```html
<table id="userTable">
  <thead>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Score</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The issue I'm having is that currently it adds all the data into one td, as opposed to seperate td's correspond to the headings. How can I append the data into seperate cells?

Comment: Well you have to create multiple td-elements like you already did with `document.createElement("td")`.

Comment: What does user contain?

Comment: You just created single td element & you have 3 variable to add to table. You must create 3 td with variable names td1,td2,td3 & append them to table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  var table = document.getElementById("userTable");

  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  var td2 = document.createElement("td");
  var td3 = document.createElement("td");

  var fn = document.createTextNode(user.firstname);
  var ln = document.createTextNode(user.lastname);
  var score = document.createTextNode(user.score);

  td1.appendChild(fn);
  td2.appendChild(ln);
  td3.appendChild(score);

  tr.appendChild(td1);
  tr.appendChild(td2);
  tr.appendChild(td3);

  table.appendChild(tr);
```

Comment: Please describe what did you change/update and are you getting the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating element using `createElement("tr")` use functions, like:
 `insertRow()` and `insertCell()` to create the table.

```js
var user = {
  firstname: "foo",
  lastname: "bar",
  score: 30
}

// getting reference to table
var table = document.getElementById("userTable");

// creating table row -> where 1 is index
var row = table.insertRow(1);

// creating cells 
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

// feeding data to the cells
cell1.innerHTML = user.firstname
cell2.innerHTML = user.lastname
cell3.innerHTML = user.score
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table id="userTable">
  <thead>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Score</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is that API supported by all browsers? The browser compatibility chart at the Mozilla Dev site doesn't look so good.

Comment: insertRow() is supported since ages. I think insertCell() too, event if the MDN page is not clear about it.

Comment: It works in IE11 and mozilla, not sure about safari. @xander

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 3 different td and append each text in them.

However, consider using `insertRow()` and `insertCell()` methods which are more easier. You'll have to target the tbody element, not the table :

**HTML :**

```
<table >
    <thead>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="userTable">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS :** (Of course, you'll prefer to use a loop here)

```
var table = document.getElementById("userTable");

var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);

var newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
var newText = document.createTextNode(user.firstname);
newCell.appendChild(newText);

var newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
var newText = document.createTextNode(user.lastname);
newCell.appendChild(newText);

var newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
var newText = document.createTextNode(user.score);
newCell.appendChild(newText);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1sg3ojkq/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell

Answer (score -2):

```js
var table = document.getElementById("userTable");
var tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");

  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td = document.createElement("td");

  var fn = document.createTextNode("James");
  var ln = document.createTextNode("Bond");
  var score = document.createTextNode("007");

  td.appendChild(fn);
  td.appendChild(ln);
  td.appendChild(score);

  tr.appendChild(td);
  tableBody.appendChild(tr);
```

```html
<table id="userTable">
    <thead>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

One more thing need to create 3 tds